# Getting files quantity and traversing them

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to read the files in a folder and then do something with them. So I need to get the number of existing files and then traverse them. I'm doing this for obtaining the quantity, but then it fails in the while.

```
#!/bin/sh
LIMIT=expr find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | wc -l;
i=1;
echo $LIMIT;
while [ "$i" -lt $LIMIT ]

Throws an error: ./converting.sh: 7: [: Illegal number:
```

What do you think I am missing? Any kind of conversion?
Thanks in advance, I'm not a bash scripter and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: Don't use `expr`.  Command substitution is what you want.  Enclose the `find ... | wc -l` command with `$(...)`.  The variable will then be set to the output of the command.   Having said that, the answers below suggesting you just find the files directly are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why your code is breaking: you forgot to use the command substitution syntax.

```
LIMIT=expr find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | wc -l;
```

The shell calls the `find` command, adding an variable `LIMIT` with the value `"expr"` to find's environment. After the `find|wc` pipeline exits, the variable `LIMIT` **does not exist**. You should have written

```
LIMIT=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | wc -l)
```

Carrying on with your code, when you get to this line, you get an error:

```
while [ "$i" -lt $LIMIT ]
```

Here, `$LIMIT` is replaced by nothing, so the shell sees `[ "$i" -lt  ]`. On my system, where /bin/sh is symlinked to bash, I get:

```
$ /bin/sh
sh-4.3$ i=10
sh-4.3$ unset LIMIT
sh-4.3$ if [ "$i" -lt $LIMIT ]; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
sh: [: 10: unary operator expected
N
```

The "unary operator" error results because I only passed 2 arguments to the `[` command. With 2 arguments, the first argument is expected to be an operator and the 2nd argument is expected to be its operand. `10` is not an operator known by the `[` command.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want a simple `for` loop with an early break:

```
LIMIT=10
for f in ./*; do
    [[ -d $f ]] && continue
    ((++i == LIMIT)) && break
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

May I offer a different approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  cat "$f"
done
```